# Sind Sätze mit »... damit, wenn ...« korrekt?

Tags: grammaticality, pronominal-adverb

In der Umgangssprache höre ich oft Sätze der Form:

> Wie wäre es damit, wenn ...?
>
> Was wäre damit, wenn ...?

Zum Beispiel:

> Was wäre damit, wenn du erstmal deine Hausaufgaben machst?

Ist das richtiges Deutsch?

Answer (score 3):

Für mich ist dieser Satz an der Grenze, ungrammatisch, oder zumindestens umgangssprachlich zu sein. Er fragt mit

> Wie wäre es damit?

was wäre, wenn etwas *mit* dabei wäre (hier die Tatsache, dass jemand seine Hausaufgaben macht).

> Wie wäre es mit Frühstück?

ist ein zulässiger Satz. (Ich bin immer froh, wenn ich "mit einem Frühstück" bin...)

> Wie wäre es, wenn du deine Hausaufgaben machst?

(Ganz richtig: *machtest*, schliesslich sollte das Konjunktiv sein) ebenfalls - Das "damit" ist also vollkommen unnötig. Ich kann aber keine Regel finden, die soche Konstruktionen explizit verbietet.